# Learning the directory's physical disk on Linux with Python

Tags: python, linux

First, sorry for my bad English.

I'm writing a python script, which compares the files in two different directories. But for performance, I want to know that: "Are the directories on the same physical disk or not?", so I can read them simultaneously for performance gain.

My current idea is getting "mount" commands output, and getting the /dev/sd* directories path and use them for identify the disks. But sometimes you can mount an already mounted directory on somewhere else(or something like that, i'm not so sure), so things get complicated.

Is there a better way to do that, like a library?

(If there is a cross-platform way, I will be more appreciated, but it seems it's hard to find a cross-platform library like this.)

Comment: Are you assuming NAS or SAN isn't involved.

Comment: I don't really know what there are :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the stat function from linux, which is also provided to you by python (see http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat).

You will have to compare the st_dev from the resulting structure and both files will be on the same filesystem if they match.

Using this function is as portable as you can get (better than mount or df).

Bonus: you do not have to run expensive exec calls and do error prone text parsing.

Comment: Thanks! It's also cross-platform, perfect for me :).

Comment: Yes. Every filesystem has a different device id when mounted; it does not matter where it resides (on a local disk, in memory - e.g. tmpfs - or on another computer on the network).

Answer (score 0):

An easier alternative to using `mount` might be to invoke `df <directory>`.

This prints out the filesystem. Also, on my Ubuntu box, passing `-P` to `df` makes the output a little bit easier to parse.

Comment: I didn't know "df [directory]", thanks, it is more easier with that(+1 :)). But I think still there could be a better way than running a command and parsing it's output.

Comment: Having had a look at `df`'s source code, I doubt that. I'd love to be proved wrong though.